# I am certain (that?) I can help (to?) improve your company

Tags: ellipsis

in a school book which has an example application letter it says the following:

> I am certain I can help improve your accounting functions while increasing your company's bottom-line profitability.

If I were to write this sentence, I would probably write this:

> I am certain **that** I can help **to** improve your accounting functions while increasing your company's bottom-line profitability.

(note I added 'that' after certain and 'to' after help)

Thank you.

Comment: Typically using parenthesis means the words within are optional; i.e. they may or may not be used in the sentence. It doesn't mean that the inclusion of the phrase in parenthesis marks the sentence as ungrammatical.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough. I mean that it said: I am certain I can help improve your accounting functions while increasing your company's bottom-line profitability. However, I would put 'that' after certain and 'to' after help. The book doesn't do this so I presume that I am wrong, why is that? EDIT: I changed the post

Comment: Why do you think you are incorrect? Both sentences mean the same thing

Comment: Oh it is correct? Thanks :) I was just afraid that I was making a mistake many times, and I didn't know how to google this.

Answer (score 3):

> "I am certain I can help improve your accounting functions while increasing your company's bottom-line profitability."

and

> "I am certain that I can help to improve your accounting functions while increasing your company's bottom-line profitability."

are both correct. In the first example, the words "that" and "to" are elided, but your version is equally valid (and some would say more complete).